# SVM vs. Ranking SVM?

Tags: svm, multilabel

I'm having a hard time visualizing Ranking SVM and would love help "drawing it out". Rank SVM is a multi-label multi-classification learning method, and Support Vector Machine was originally intended for single-label learning.

What are the differences imposed in rank SVM that allows for the novel structure of multi-label datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this paper:
Elisseeff, André, and Jason Weston. "A kernel method for multi-labelled classification." Advances in neural information processing systems. 2002.